# How to install Fortran compiler (gcc42-fortran)

Tags: linux, r, fortran

I'm trying to install R and came across this error during installation: http://projects.uabgrid.uab.edu/r-group/wiki/install-R, which is why i need to install the fortran compiler. Every .rpm i have downloaded of the gcc42.fortran has given me this error:

> libgfortran2 >= 4.2.1_20070724-50.18
>   is needed by package
>   gcc42-fortran-4.2.1_20070724-50.18.i586
>   (/gcc42-fortran-4.2.1_20070724-50.18.i586)
>   gcc42 = 4.2.1_20070724-50.18 is needed
>   by package
>   gcc42-fortran-4.2.1_20070724-50.18.i586
>   (/gcc42-fortran-4.2.1_20070724-50.18.i586)

Is there an easier way of installing it? Like via yum?

---

EDIT

I got gcc installed, but im rather confused in the link provided as how to apply the patch at step 8.

Comment: This question is probably better at superuser.com

Comment: That link looks a little wonky- it suggests modifying the `configure` script when the "normal" approach to specifying a fortran compiler is via setting the `FC` or `F77` environment variables before running the configure script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the package manager? For example, Ubuntu's Synaptic Package Manager has a package called `gfortran`. The package manager should take care of dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Editing or patching the configure script is not a good idea. The file to edit would be `configure.ac`. But for just using a different compiler there's no need to change anything. You can run:

```
FC=gfortran-4.2 F77=gfortran-4.2 ./configure
```

For more details see `./configure --help`.

The easier way to install would indeed be `yum install R`.